# SQL row output like column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My table design as follows:

BSales:

```
PCode SaleDate      SaleValue
1     2015-01-01    50000
2     2015-01-01    50000
3     2015-01-01    50000
4     2015-01-01    50000
5     2015-01-01    50000
1     2015-01-02    50000
2     2015-01-02    50000
3     2015-01-02    50000
4     2015-01-02    50000
5     2015-01-02    50000


select PCode,SaleDate,SUM(SaleValue) as Sales 
from [BSales] 
where SaleDate between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-05' 
group by PCode,SaleDate
```

this partialy fulfil my desire output.But i want to the output as follows:

```
 PCode  '2015-01-01'    '2015-01-02'    '2015-01-03'    '2015-01-04'    '2015-01-05'
 1      5000            50000           0               0               0    
 2      5000            50000           0               0               0    
 3      5000            50000           0               0               0    
 4      5000            50000           0               0               0    
 5      5000            50000           0               0               0
```

Is it Possible using sql query?or T-SQL?Or using Store Procedure?Anybody helps is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the pivot options in T-SQL.

For example (not tested!)

```
SELECT *
FROM BSales
PIVOT(SUM(SaleValue) 
          FOR SaleDate IN ([2015-01-01], [2015-01-02]
                       , [2015-01-03], [2015-01-04], [2015-01-05])) AS PVTTable
```

Here's a full tutorial on it.

http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/10/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

This is pivot task:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      PCode INT ,
      SaleDate DATE ,
      SaleValue MONEY
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, '2015-01-01', 50000 ),
        ( 2, '2015-01-01', 50000 ),
        ( 3, '2015-01-01', 50000 ),
        ( 4, '2015-01-01', 50000 ),
        ( 5, '2015-01-01', 50000 ),
        ( 1, '2015-01-02', 50000 ),
        ( 2, '2015-01-02', 50000 ),
        ( 3, '2015-01-02', 50000 ),
        ( 4, '2015-01-02', 50000 ),
        ( 5, '2015-01-02', 50000 )

SELECT  PCode ,
        ISNULL([2015-01-01], 0) AS [2015-01-01] ,
        ISNULL([2015-01-02], 0) AS [2015-01-02] ,
        ISNULL([2015-01-03], 0) AS [2015-01-03] ,
        ISNULL([2015-01-04], 0) AS [2015-01-04] ,
        ISNULL([2015-01-05], 0) AS [2015-01-05]
FROM    @t PIVOT( MAX(SaleValue) FOR SaleDate IN ( [2015-01-01], [2015-01-02],
                                                   [2015-01-03], [2015-01-04],
                                                   [2015-01-05] ) ) p
```

Output:

```
PCode   2015-01-01  2015-01-02  2015-01-03  2015-01-04  2015-01-05
1       50000.00    50000.00    0           0           0
2       50000.00    50000.00    0           0           0
3       50000.00    50000.00    0           0           0
4       50000.00    50000.00    0           0           0
5       50000.00    50000.00    0           0           0
```